Spring JPA performant treat() statement
Jpa offers the treat() operator that allows for using child fields in queries designed for parents in inheritance entity relationships. One such relationship could be
@Entity
@Table("table")
@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator_type")
class Parent {
    int foo; 
    /*plus definition of PK and other fields*/
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CHILD")
class Child extends Parent {
    int bar;
}

Thus, in a @Query on a JpaRepository<Parent, Long> like
@Query("select treat(parent as Child).bar from Parent parent where parent.id = ?1")

the generated query does an inner join on Parent and Child, even though they are the same table in the database. I am wondering if this can be forced to avoid an unnecessary inner join. Although this result can be achieved via a native query, I am looking specifically for a non-native solution.
This has been already discussed in this SO question, and I am curious if there are any improvements on the situation today.
